# Why 'Mrs.' isn't read as 'mistress'?

Tags: etymology, abbreviations

Wasn't *Mrs.* short for *mistress*? Why do we read *Mrs.* as *missus*(or sometimes *missis*) instead of *mistress*?

Comment: +1 This is a question I never thought to ask. But now you've asked it, I'm surprised I've never questioned it myself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It *is* read as mistress, albeit a contracted form of it, just like *ma'am* is a popular contraction of *madam*. Quoting [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mrs.):

> Mrs. originated as a contraction of the honorific Mistress, the
>   feminine of Mister, or Master, which was originally applied to both
>   married and unmarried women. The split into Mrs. for married women
>   from Ms. and Miss began during the 17th century.
>
> It is rare for Mrs. to be written in a non-abbreviated form, and the
>   word lacks a standard phonetic spelling. In literature it may appear
>   as *missus* or *missis* in dialogue. *A variant in the works of Thomas
>   Hardy and others is "Mis'ess", reflecting its etymology.*

Comment: See also the comments [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/11829/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

Mr(s) is a reference to the feminine of "Mr." The most common reference is to "missus," (a female "mister" if you will), although it could also be a reference to "mistress" (a female master).